# How calculate the number prorated day with Stripe API?

Tags: ruby

i am using Stripe. I would like to know how can calculate number of day prorated

I want display something like that

> 1 additional seat ($9/month each - prorated for 26 days)

in the api i don't see any item prorate_day

Bolo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subscription_proration_date` what you are looking for? Then it will calculate it for you.

See more at https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/guide

The example of pro-rated subscription in ruby is as follows

```
# Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
# See your keys here https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
Stripe.api_key = "sk_test_9OkpsFpKa1HDHaZa7e0BeGaO"

proration_date = Time.now.to_i
invoice = Stripe::Invoice.upcoming(:customer => "cus_3R1W8PG2DmsmM9", :subscription => "sub_3R3PlB2YlJe84a",
                                   :subscription_plan => "premium_monthly", :subscription_proration_date => proration_date)
current_prorations = invoice.lines.data.select { |ii| ii.period.start == proration_date }
cost = 0
current_prorations.each do |p|
  cost += p.amount
end

# Display the cost of these prorations invoice items to the end user,
# and actually do the update when they agree.
# To make sure that the proration is calculated the same as when it was previewed,
# you need to pass in the proration_date parameter

# later...

subscription = Stripe::Subscription.retrieve("sub_3R3PlB2YlJe84a")
subscription.plan = "premium_monthly"
subscription.proration_date = proration_date
subscription.save
```